# Getting a Cross-Section from Two CSV Files

Tags: openoffice, mysql, csv

I have two CSV files that I am working with. One is massive, with about 200,000 rows. The other is much smaller, having about 12,000 rows. Both fit the same format of names, and email addresses (everything is legit here, no worries). Basically I'm trying to get only a subset of the second list by removing all values that presently exist in the larger file.

So, List A has ~200k rows, and List B has ~12k. These lists overlap a bit, and I'd like to remove all entries from List B if they also exist in List A, leaving me with new and unique values only in List B. I've got a few tooks at my disposal that I can use. Open Office is loaded on this machine, along with MySQL (queries are alright).

What's the easiest way to create a third CSV with the intersection of data?

Answer (score 4):

From a Linux/Unix/Mac command-line:

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq -d | sort file2 - | uniq -u
```

#### Explanation:

This returns only those lines in file2 that do not exactly match any line in file1.

#### Steps:

1. `sort file1 file2`: Concatenates file1 and file2 together, sorts them, and prints them to stdout. Note that duplicates will be listed in adjacent lines (twice in a row) after sorting.
2. `uniq -d`: Takes the output of the previous command and prints **only the lines that are duplicates**.
3. `sort file2 -`: Concatenates the original file2 and the output of the previous command (stdout, which is represented by the filename "`-`" hyphen), and prints the result to stdout. In addition, any items in file2 which were also in file1 will be duplicated (listed twice in a row) in the output.
4. `uniq -u`: Takes the output of the previous command and prints only items which are not duplicated (in other words, prints only items which are not listed twice in a row).

#### Possible gotchas:

This assumes that any given line in file1 *exactly matches* a corresponding line in file2. If, for example, file1 and file2 had the same e-mail but with different capitalization; or if file1 had a name as "Jon Sampson" while file2 had the same e-mail address with the name "Jonathan Sampson", they would not be considered duplicates.

You could control for this by pre-processing the file to remove everything except the e-mail address, and further, lowercase the e-mail address. The Unix commands `cut` and `tr` could be helpful in this case. Or you could switch to SQL for more complex scenarios.

#### File size:

A file of 200,000 lines and one of 12,000 lines is not really that big. I generated files of similar size using the `/usr/share/dict/words` file on my MacBook Pro and tested the above command; it took less than 5 seconds to run.

Answer (score 2):

[Nate](https://superuser.com/users/4850/nate) has given you a really good answer, but there is a <strike>shorter</strike> longer way from a Linux/Unix/Mac command-line:

```
join -t# -v2 <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) > result.csv
```

Caveats:

- The original question is about joining whole lines. The only way I can think of
  suppressing `join`'s need to split, is to define the field delimiter as a character 
  that is not used in any of the files (`#` in my example). Ugly, I know.
- Input files must be sorted on the join field. You can do this in one line (see above)
  but it will only work in `bash`. Other shells have different syntax for this.

If your input files are sorted:

```
join -t# -v2 file1.csv file2.csv > result.csv
```

For Windows there is a [native port of join](http://www.wzw.tum.de/~syring/win32/UnxUtilsDist.html) .

Comment: Wow! I did not know about `join`. You learn something new every day.

Comment: How would I pass the output into a third CSV?

Comment: Hmmm... this seems to be giving me lines from file2 which match lines from file1. He needs to get lines that do not match. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, -a2 is a right outer join. If you only want the unpairable lines it's -v.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: You can use a pipe to write it in a file like so: join -v2 file1.csv file2.csv > result.csv

Comment: Hmm... that works better, but I am still getting one duplicate that I am not seeing when using the `sort | uniq` method. Since the files are huge I can't demo it here, but I'll try to get a smaller test case.

Comment: It appears to be related to case-sensitivity and sort order. Note that **the files must be sorted** according to the `man` page for `join`. After sorting both files, it works properly. (The files I was testing with were sorted in a non-case-sensitive way.)

Comment: @Nate: Per default the command joins on the first (space delimited) field.
The easiest fix is to use a character that isn't in your file (maybe #) as a field delimiter, like this: join -t# -v2 file1.csv file2.csv >result.csv

Another thing I just realized is that your input files have to be sorted for join to work properly.

Comment: Note to self: Never post, not even a one-liner, without having tested it;-). I have incorporated your suggestions in my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Looks great; I'll test this out momentarily.